# Can we change width of container in css using Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, width, containers

how can i change width of container in bootstrap3. I want content in center of browser (70% of browser's width).

```
               <p>

                 Use Bootply to design, prototype, or test the Bootstrap framework. Find examples, share code and rapidly build interfaces for Bootstrap. 
                 Use Bootply to design, prototype, or test the Bootstrap framework. Find examples, share code and rapidly build interfaces for Bootstrap. 
              </p>
               <p>

Use Bootply to design, prototype, or test the Bootstrap framework. Find examples, share code and rapidly build interfaces for Bootstrap. 
              Use Bootply to design, prototype, or test the Bootstrap framework. Find examples, share code and rapidly build interfaces for Bootstrap. 


            </p><p>
            Positive Energy By Nature <br>
            Sun is always there for us
            </p>

            <p>
                Use Bootply to design, prototype, or test the Bootstrap framework. Find examples, share code and rapidly build interfaces for Bootstrap. 
            </p>
            </div>
```

[Please check my code](http://www.bootply.com/Z7bIKrTVag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surround your p tags in a

```
<div class="container">
```

Then in your css file declare something like:

```
.container {
  max-width: 70%;
}
```

I hope that this will help you :)

But instead of 70% it is better to declare max-width precisely...like `max-width: 1100px;`

Comment: thank  you so much for your response ;)
One more thing i want to ask. I want my site to look like this website in mobile but i don't know how to manage navigation bar. Here is link http://www.sevenkoncepts.com/

Comment: Go to Bootstrap's website and grab the navigation code...drop it in your files and style everything accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new style. Name it styl.css. Afterwards, search bootstrap3 folder. You will find bootstrap.min.css. Type `Ctrl+F` and search for "container" class. Modify it.

for example,

```
.container{
    width:70;
}
```

I hope that will help you.